# Why is the msgqueue built automatically each time when the os restarted?

Tags: c, linux, ipc

my program use a system msgqueue for ipc .my code:

```
  key = 0x0000ed79;
    if( ( id=msgget(key,0666|IPC_CREAT)) <=  0 )
            return  false ;
      else  return  true
```

the problem is:

1. every time the machine is restarted,there is msgqueue automatically built with the same key but with its id of 0,so i have to ipcrm it;
2. why can not i use a msgqueue with an id of 0? here is the description of the return value of the msgget api within man page,it seems an id of 0 is not incorrect :

   > If successful, the return value will be the message queue identifier(a nonnegative integer), otherwise -1 with errno indicating the error

Comment: msgQs are kernel persistent and don't survive a reboot.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: msgget might return an queue id of 0, there's nothing special about 0. msgget returns -1 on failure. (Though, if you get back a queue id after a reboot that you did not create yourself, it may be your key clashes with some other process)

Comment: @nos.how to find which process create the queue with the same key?tks

Answer (score 0):

> how to find which process create the queue with the same key?

There is no easy way to find which process created the queue, but we can inspect the processes that sent to or received from the queue lastly, and maybe the creating process is one of those (and even if not, identifying the processes using the queue may help), e. g. for the *msqid 0*

```
ipcs -qi0
```

displays `lspid=… lrpid=…` - the process IDs of the last processes to send/receive a message
                     from the associated message queue.